# Water Simulation not rendering the right way

Tags: rendering

Water is not looking like it should With Glass
[image]

Comment: You may need to set the water simulation to final instead of preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to refine your outcome.

- Most important for fine results: Increase the value for *final resolution*.
- Increase values for smoothing and smoothing subdivisions under *Fluid Boundary*.
- Use a *Smooth Modifier* on your water object. Values like *Repeat: 50* may be necessary.

Comment: Even the material looks wrong, did u set it to glass? (this ends up looking like water if you set the IOR to 1.3333)